# php add and merge data from two table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query from first table:

```
     $this->db->table('categories')
        ->select('id, name, parent_id')
        ->orderBy('parent_id')
        ->get()
        ->getResultObject();
```

data output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => cat1
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => cat2
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => cat5
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => cat6
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => cat3
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => cat4
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

)
```

and query for second table:

```
$this->db->table('post_category')
    ->select('category_id')
    ->where('post_id', $id)
    ->get()->getResultObject();
```

output data is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 4
        )

)
```

Now I need to add selected in array and add data(category_id) from table two in table one if (category_id = id) like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => cat1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [selected] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => cat2
            [parent_id] => 0
            [selected] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => cat5
            [parent_id] => 0
            [selected] => 
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => cat6
            [parent_id] => 0
            [selected] => 
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => cat3
            [parent_id] => 2
            [selected] => 
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => cat4
            [parent_id] => 2
            [selected] => 1
        )

)
```

How do can i add data from table two in table one(if category_id from table two = id from table one) like my last output?!

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Comment: @ikiK: please add answer with data for check and tick if sloved problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to populate the `['selected']` item of a subarray in the first array ("categories") with "1" based on whether there's a "post_category" with that value you can do this:

```
foreach ($categories as &$category) {
    $filtered_post_categories = array_filter($post_categories, function($post_category) use ($category) {
        return $post_category->category_id == $category->id;
    });

    if (count($filtered_post_categories) > 0) {
        $category->selected = 1;
    }
    else {
        $category->selected = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code will modify the first array you provided, so print it out however you like/need for your use. `var_dump($categories);` would spit out what you said you wanted in the OP.

Comment: Sure, not true work. in action for my data, your code add selected to first array with id = 1 but i need to add selected to categories array for id =1 and id = 4. can u update your answer with data for better choice, please.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it. The `break` line actual broke the functionality.